# how to return list for eager compilation?

Tags: numba

The `numba` allows eager compilation by telling the function signature. But, I can not find some information about the list type. My test code is:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

# @nb.jit(nb.ListType())
def Cal():
    return [1, np.zeros(shape=[5, 5]), 3]

a = Cal()
```

What's the function signature for `Cal`?

In addition, what if there are three outputs? How to provide the function signature? For example:

```
def TwoOutput():
   return 1, 2
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return the list `[1, np.zeros(shape=[5, 5]), 3]` from a Numba jitted function. In fact, if you try, Numba will throw few error saying that the "*compilation is falling back to* **object mode** *WITH looplifting enabled because Function "Cal" failed type inference*" due to the output type being not well defined. Indeed, the type of the items in the list needs to be all the same and not objects (called typed list). This is not the case here (reflected list). Reflected lists are not supported by Numba (anymore). What makes Numba fast is the type inference enabling it to generate a fast native code. With Python dynamic objects there is no way to generate a fast code (due to many heavy overhead like type checking, reference counting, allocations, etc.).

Note that you can return a tuple if the output always have the same *small* number of item defined at *compile-time*. Also note that **Numba can automatically infer the output type so you can use `@nb.jit(`()`)` here to enable the eager compilation** of the target function.

Put it shortly, **Numba is not meant to support/speed-up this use-case**. Note that Cython can and be slightly faster. You need not to use reflected lists (nor dynamic objects) if you want to get a fast code.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. `Numba can automatically infer the output type` Does the inference cost time in the first compilation? What if `Cal` return `[1, 2, 3]`? What the function signature should be?

Comment: The inference happens anyway but I do not know if specifying the type make the compilation faster. I never saw any impact on the compilation time. Generally, most of the time taken comes from the optimization of the code and not the type inference. If `Cal` would return `[1, 2, 3]` then the function signature should be something like `nb.types.List(nb.int64)()`. Note Numba automatically converts returned typed lists to reflected lists for convenience (and performance since manipulating typed list from a pure-Python code is slow).